# What is this 4-1/2 inch Vertical metal pipe doing in my garden?

Tags: pipe, backyard, utilities

This 4 1/2 inch vertical metal pipe is sticking up a foot out of my garden.
The previous owner of the property didn't know what it was for.  It has 2 hose clamps on it and a cap with a square nipple.

The city utilities don't have a record of its existence.

I want to take it out, but I also want to get as much info as I can about it before I accidentally bust a necessary fixture. Also, there is another building with all utilities on the back of my property. House on property was built in 1983, if that helps.  All the relevant utility companies have said it is not theirs.

Anybody ever work with something like it?

UPDATE -- Definitely Drain Cleanout.  I loosened the hose clamps and the top came right off and I could see "liquid" about 3-1/2 feet down.

[image: Vertical Metal Pipe]

Comment: What's under the lid?  That will almost certainly help to answer your question.

Comment: Do you (or did you) have an underground heating oil tank?

Comment: I haven't messed with the lid/cap yet (if it is pressurized water, I want to be ready).  If it was an oil tank, the previous owner of the property was unaware of it.

Comment: Looks like a sewer clean out pipe to me.  If that's what it is, it's the homeowner's responsibility, not your town/city/county's.  Which is why your utility companies are taking a pass.

Comment: Does (or did) this house ever have a septic system, or has it always been on a public sewer system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really looks like a drain cleanout. Since it's on your property the city utilities probably won't have a record of it. It could have been added after the house was built and never needed by the previous owner. Remove that cap and see what's down there. Turn on some water or flush a few toilets and see if you see water flowing.

Comment: And don't worry, the drain isn't pressurized, nothing will splash out at you. (Addressing the OPs concern in a comment on the OP.)

Comment: why would a cleanout have hose clamps attached?

Comment: Probably won't be able to *see* water flowing, but it could be audible. More tests for the sewer cleanout hypothesis: find out where the sewer main is located; does this stand between the main and the house? Remove the cap and listen for sounds inside the pipe. If a car runs over a nearby sewer manhole cover in the street, or an assistant strikes a manhole cover with a hammer or rock, do you hear those sounds transmitted through this pipe?

Comment: @dandavis I think outdoor cleanout caps are almost universally attached to the pipe in this way. The cap itself is likely brass; it probably threads into a cast iron piece; these are commonly connected to the PVC or iron sewer pipe by a rubber coupler with clamps as shown in the photo.

Comment: @dandavis That's a drain coupling. Maybe they extended it to a new grade level.

Comment: @JACK Not necessarily: the vertical cleanout pipe may (should?) connect to the main line with a wye fitting. If the branch of the wye is long, or if it's a 45 degree wye plus a 45 degree elbow, then it may not be possible to see the main line flow.

Comment: Do any of you know if I need to get special permission to lower the grade/ shorten the pipe a couple feet? (independent of who does the work)

Comment: It's your pipe but if indeed it's a sewer cleanout, it may be required to be above a certain level to prevent any surface water from entering.  Check with your local building codes authority.

Comment: The caps are usually brass and the pipe cast iron. Often the threads will be corroded stuck so that the cap must be destroyed to remove it. Plumbers know how to do this with minimal obvious change in the cap which they just place on, but then it is no longer tight. I replaced mine with plastic and lubed the threads with silicone grease. The threads on one of two cast iron pipes were so corroded that I could only engage one or two threads.